# PhpStorm built-in server serving 301 error

Tags: php, apache, redirect, phpstorm

I'm trying to run the built-in web server for PhpStorm with PHP 7 and port set to 3000. Every time I try to connect the server logs a `301 error` and redirects to the root directory of my Apache 2 install. I am also running Apache 2 but tried stopping the service.

Didn't know if anyone else was having this error?

Comment: Use Apache for your all web server needs -- it's better than built-in one.

Comment: I currently run gulp for my sass files, and it's kindof a pain to have to run gulp in apache (I can't get the compiled files to save from php storm to the server without an explicit push (annoying)) and then edit the files in phpstorm and then switch back to apache to push the compiled files to git. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea how running a gulp task is related to Apache (or built-in web server) here... Sorry, cannot really help on this one.